# AWS Lambda - Node JS - Lambda (perhaps) exits early?

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, async-await, amazon-sqs

I have an issue with a lambda function I am developing for a personal project - budget/payment system. The intent of the lambda is to pull messages from an SQS queue, each record/message is processed by the lambda where some helper functions (`calcDateUsingDayInterval()` and `calcMonths()` - these use a lambda layer for dependency and utilise the `date-fns` JS library) are called to plot out dates, based on input frequency. The idea is that these output dates will be added to another SQS queue, and then processed by a rest API (lambda) which will POST records to a dynamodb table. BUT for now, I am just trying to log each output to show that the function is actually working. When this lambda is invoked by the event source mapping attached to the queue, it looks like the function exits early and doesnt wait for the result.

I have been developing the function just using nodejs locally, and then lifting the config into lambda. When I run this in nodejs locally, I get the expected output (logged events based on "frequency".) Here is my lambda code:

```
const {
    addDays,
    addMonths,
    differenceInCalendarMonths,
    eachDayOfInterval,
    formatISO,
  } = require("date-fns");
  const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
  
  exports.handler = async function (event, context) {
    event.Records.forEach((record) => {
      const { body } = record;
      console.log(body); // I can see this in cloudwatch logs
  
      // Day Function
      function calcDateUsingDayInterval(startDate, endDate, step) {
        const dayRange = eachDayOfInterval(
          { start: startDate, end: endDate },
          { step: step }
        );
  
        dayRange.forEach((day) => {
          console.log({
            id: AWS.util.uuid.v4(),
            parentId: body.parentId,
            date: formatISO(day, { representation: "date" }),
            name: body.name,
            description: body.description,
            vendor: body.vendor,
            frequency: body.frequency,
            value: body.value,
            type: body.type,
            status: body.status,
            forecastId: body.forecastId,
            event_time: new Date().toISOString(),
          });
        });
      }
  
      // Month Function
      function calcMonths(endDate, startDate, step) {
        // Calculate the number of months in the date range - used as the condition in the loop
        const months = differenceInCalendarMonths(endDate, startDate);
        // Iterate through the number of months by the step range
        for (let i = step; i <= months; i += step) {
          const date = addMonths(startDate, i);
          console.log({
            id: AWS.util.uuid.v4(),
            parentId: body.parentId,
            date: formatISO(date, { representation: "date" }),
            name: body.name,
            description: body.description,
            vendor: body.vendor,
            frequency: body.frequency,
            value: body.value,
            type: body.type,
            status: body.status,
            forecastId: body.forecastId,
            event_time: new Date().toISOString(),
          });
        }
      }
  
      try { // This does nothing in the lambda function - but works in node locally
          switch (body.frequency) {
              case 0:
                  calcDateUsingDayInterval(body.startDate, body.startDate, 1)
              break;
              case 1:
                  calcDateUsingDayInterval(body.startDate, body.endDate, 1)
              break;
              case 2:
                  calcDateUsingDayInterval(body.startDate, body.endDate, 7)
              break;
              case 3:
                  calcDateUsingDayInterval(body.startDate, body.endDate, 14)
              break;
              case 4:
                  calcMonths(body.endDate, body.startDate, 1)
              break;
              case 5:
                  calcMonths(body.endDate, body.startDate, 3)
              break;
              case 6:
                  calcDateUsingDayInterval(body.startDate, body.endDate, 365)
              break;
              default:
                  throw new Error(`Unsupported frequency integer: "${body.frequency}"`)
          }
      }
      catch {
          // To do
      }
      finally {
          // To do
      }
    });
    return {};
  };
```

Based on my research I expect this is something to do with my lambda handler function being Async, because of this it looks like I need to return a promise. I dont properly understand JS promises - tried a few things and couldnt get it to work. I am a self taught hack.

**Questions**

1. Does this lambda handler even need to be Async if its processing messages from an SQS queue? - Number of functions should scale horizontally based on input.
2. Can this be optimised so my helper functions werent inside `event.Records.forEach`? I guess I could use a lambda layer for this also? Any help with code formatting to optimise/minimise invocation run time is also appreciated. I wasnt sure how to get access to the `body` object for logging if the functions were outside the loop.

Thanks

Comment: The `catch` is probably swallowing the `error` information.

Comment: Thanks... this was a silly mistake, but you helped me identify the solution!